# Converting prefix to infix in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, math, expression, prefix, infix-notation

I am trying to write a program that takes in an prefix expression and outputs an infix expression. I have examples listed below to help demonstrate what I am talking about. I have pasted my code below, could someone please help me figure out how I can move the symbol between 2 numbers in an expression? Please see example 1 to see my approach on how I tried to get it, but it doesn't work. Any answers would be helpful or tips as to what to do. Thank you for your help!

```
/* The goal is to take in an expression in prefix notation and output it in infix notation
for example:
 + 1 2 outputs output 1 + 2
 + - 3 4 5 outputs 3 + 4 - 5
 % + / - 0 9 3 8 5 outputs 0 % 9 + 3 / 8 - 5 
*/

function convert(input){
  var x = input.split(''); // splits each variable and stores it in an array
  var output = "";
  // these are the valid symbols we can take, we will use these later
  var symbols = ['+', '-', '*', '/', '%'];
  // lets loop through all the values in x, starting at position 0
  for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
    if(symbols.includes(x[i])) { // we hit a symbol, lets move it between 2 numbers
      /* now we need to figure out where to store the symbol. every 2 spaces starting at index 0
       we can insert a symbol (so spots like 1 3 5 7 etc). this loop will help us figure out what spot is empty
       , and it will store the symbol at that spot [see example 1 for a visualizaton]*/
      for(var j = 0; j < input.length; j+=2){
        if(output[j] == " "){
         // great, we can save the symbol here 
          output = output + x[i];
        }
      }
    }
    // otherwise we have a number on our hands
    else{
      output = output + x[i];
      console.log(output);
    }
  }
}

console.log(convert("+ 1 2"));

/*
example 1

if I have "+ 1 2"

+ is position 0
1 is position 2
2 is position 4

so the whitespace is at position 1 and 3. these are the spots where we can output the symbols
using the original expression + 1 2

position:  value:
-------- | ------
0        |    1
-------- | ------
1        |   " "
-------- | ------
2        |    +
-------- | ------
3        |   " "
-------- | ------
4        |    2

*/
```

Comment: That's an unusual definition of prefix notation, as normally the last operator is applied to the first operands that follow it. So normally `+ - 3 4 5` would output `3 - 4 + 5`, not `3 + 4 - 5`. Are you sure you have the examples right?

Comment: What with precedence rules in infix notation? Don't you need to insert brackets to ensure the order of evaluation is as intended by the prefix notation? Also, what if the operators are not all at the start of the prefix input, like `- / 9 3 + 2 4`. What would be the output? Normally that would be equivalent to `9 / 3 - (2 + 4)`...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So long as you're only using simple expressions, I would suggest dividing the input into two arrays, numbers and symbols, and then merging them together.

```
var symbols = ['+', '-', '*', '/', '%'];

function convert(input) {
  var
    response = '',
    infixes = [],
    numbers = [];

  // Divide input into two arrays, infixes (or symbols) and numbers
  infixes = input.split(' ').filter(function(o) {
    if (symbols.includes(o)) {
      return true;
    } else {
      numbers.push(o);
    }
  });

  // Merge arrays
  for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    if (infixes[i]) {
      response =
        response +
        numbers[i] + ' ' +
        infixes[i] + ' ';
    } else {
      response =
        response + numbers[i] + ' ';
    }
  }

  response = response.slice(0, -1);

  return response;
};
```

This function works for all your examples, but if you need to make it more intelligent you can easily modify and test the above function on codepen [here](https://codepen.io/josh_minkler/pen/eYmZywB).

Comment: Thats a nice approach! I was thinking about doing that instead when I went to bed last night. Thank you so much for your answer!

Comment: This is not a correct solution. Eg. the string "* a + b c" outputs "a * b + c" instead of "a * (b + c)".

Answer (score 0):

```
function result_expression(expression, variables) {

    let opernads=['+','-','*','/'];

let arr=[...expression.split(" ")];



var len=arr.length;






while(len>0){

   
    let d1=arr[len-1]
    let d2=arr[len-2]
    let d3=arr[len-3]
 

    if(opernads.includes(d3)){

        if(isNaN(d2)){

            let tmp=variables[d2]
            d2=tmp;
        }
                if(isNaN(d1)){

            let tmp1=variables[d1]
            d1=tmp1;
        }

      
        let a=d2.toString().concat(d3).concat(d1)

       delete arr[len-1]
       delete arr[len-2]
       delete arr[len-3]


       let na=[];

       

       arr[len-3]=eval(a)

       arr.forEach(e=>{

        if(!(typeof e==='undefined')){

            na.push(e)
        }
       })

       arr=[...na]

console.log('arr',arr)

len=arr.length;

    // arr=[...newar]

    // len=arr.length
   
    }else{


        len--
    }

   
if(len==1){

    return arr[0]
}


}









}


//let expression="+ 6 * - 4 + 2 3 8";
//let expression="+ 6 * - 4 a b + 2 3 8";
let expression="+ * 6 5 3 2 2";





let variables={a:20,b:1}
let k=result_expression(expression, variables);

console.log('finalresult',k)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).